# getting System.InvalidCastException in console application c#

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, console-application

I want to find the Median of a column in my datatable and I am getting `System.InvalidCastException` error in my console application, is there any way to sort this out?
datatable

[image: datatable col image]

**DataTable can also cantain string value like (ggg,htt,yy) or any special character like %,$,#,@,!,*,& or Null or empty string  which need to be ignone**

```
        Program p = new Program();
           double  med=p.GetMedianFromDataTable(csvData, "Data Value");


public double GetMedianFromDataTable(DataTable dt, string columnName)
        {
            //extract data from datacolumn and build and a double array
            double[] values =
             Array.ConvertAll<DataRow, double>(
               dt.Select(),
               delegate (DataRow row) { return (double)row[columnName]; } //getting error here
             );
            return GetMedianFromArray(values);
        }

        public double GetMedianFromArray(double[] values)
        {
            double median;
            //sort the array
            Array.Sort(values);
            if (values.Length % 2 != 0)
            {
                median = values[values.Length / 2];
            }
            else
            {
                int middle = values.Length / 2;
                double first = values[middle];
                double second = values[middle - 1];
                median = (first + second) / 2;
            }
            return median;
        }
```

Comment: please add a snapshot of the column data, are you sure the data in this column is `double`?

Comment: done image added @styx

Comment: what is the dataType of csvData?

Comment: also.where you are getting Exception?

Comment: datatable @HazarathChillara and commented for the line where getting error

Comment: What is the type of `row[columnName]`? Try to add a line `Debug.WriteLine(td.Rows[0][columnName].GetType());` to `GetMedianFromDataTable`. I suspect (since there is a `csv` tag, the type is string *(because all csv data are strings by default)*.

Comment: name =string @Julo

Comment: When the values are strings, then you need to parse the value. See answer from Richardissimo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is telling you that not all the values are doubles. I'm guessing that the values in your data table are strings since the question does not make that clear. This linq statement will pick out the values that are doubles and convert them. Note this uses inline declaration of variable for tryparse, which won't work on older C# compilers)

```
double[] values = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    .Select(dr=>dr[columnName].ToString())
    .Where(v=>double.TryParse(v, out double ignore))
    .Select(v=>double.Parse(v))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: @nikhiljain it is not possible to get a `InvalidCastException`from  this code. What exception are you getting and from where?

Comment: so u are converting string to double correct in ur answer ? @richard

Comment: @nikhiljain or is it possible that one of the `dr[columnName]` evaluates to `null`? Actually ignore that - that would be a NullReferenceException, and you're saying it's still giving an InvalidCastException even though there is no casting here...

Comment: It's CSV data. It should never be `double` from the start.

Comment: can be NULL(presently no null data is there)

Comment: @nikhiljain I've tried my solution with a table where a row for that column has null, and it's better than I thought, because it still works.

Comment: @Richardissimo CSV is often parsed using data tables, and the code shows the original variable given as arg to `GetMedianFromDataTable` is called `csvData`. So the data is read from a CSV file, and can thus be assumed to be strings. Could still contain `null` values though.

Comment: Sorry, your double handling code confused me. You're parsing everything _twice_ just to check if it can be parsed... seems a bit unnecessary to me, just for the sake of a one-liner.

Comment: can there be 1 more check if the value is numeric (don't want user to print alphabets or special characters) !!

Comment: and NULL also @Richardissimo

Comment: @nikhiljain My answer already filters out any values which can not be parsed into doubles (that's the "Where(TryParse)" bit), and as I mentioned earlier, I tested my code by poking a null value into a row for the given column and it worked fine for me. So I don't understand what you're asking about checking whether the value is numeric or null, or what you mean by "don't want user to print alphabets".

Comment: Alpabets or string(abcd) or any special characters like ($,!,@,#,^,*,&,/) i want to ignore them !! @richard

Comment: @nikhiljain It already does: "double.TryParse" will attempt to convert a string into a double (there are similar methods for `int`, `long`, etc) If it succeeds, it will return true. The statement in my answer only puts things into 'values' which have passed this check.

Comment: what abt special charters ike ($,!,@,#,^,*,&,/)  ?

Comment: @nikhiljain Any string which contains those characters is not a double, and will be ignored, as I already said in my previous two comments. You should have tried it yourself before you even asked, and if there is a problem, give a specific example which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try it in the old fashion way

```
   List<double> list = new List<double>();          
   foreach (var row in dt.AsEnumerable())
   {
       if (row.ItemArray[0] != DBNull.Value)
       {
           list.Add(Convert.ToDouble(row.ItemArray[0]));
        }

    }
```

and here's the [dataset](https://ibb.co/gB0kAS)

Comment: still getting same error @styx(i am reading the data from excel not from sql)

Comment: @nikhiljain so why don't you add excel tag to the question :(

Comment: it's csv actually sorry for the trouble

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

Comment: @nikhiljain can you please add a snapshot of the dataTable itself?

Comment: added in the Question itself.

Comment: i don't see it
you have the CSV in your answer but no the DataTable

Comment: i have added the snapshot of the colmun of the Datatable in the Question pls let me what more do u Require

Comment: what if NULL also comes @styx

Comment: @nikhiljain, when do you say do you mean an empty row?

Comment: @nikhiljain don't you see the if? i updated the dateTable picture

Comment: oh..missed it !!

Comment: please tell me if it works, and don't forget to mark as answer if does

Answer (score -1):

Just replace

```
{ return (double)row[columnName]; }
```

with

```
{
    Double pval;
    Double.TryParse(row[columnName], out pval);
    return pval;
}
```

If the parse did *not* succeed, `pval` will contain the default value for the type `double`, which is simply `0`.